# Allow single county gives empty drop down options in front-end checkout Country field in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, country-regions

We have configured **Allow Countries** to **Canada** in admin. On fronted, by default the checkout page country field is loading with **Canada**, but if we click on country drop down, empty drop-down fields are displaying.

Reference code.

```
<option value=""> </option>
<option data-title="" value=""></option>
<option data-title="Canada" value="CA">Canada</option>
```

Reference image.
[image]

Can any one help us on restricting country field to only one country instead of displaying **empty** or **please select** value options, so that allowed country can be one country by default and country field is non-select.

Answer (score 5):

You can create the after plugin , this logic is work fine for me , to remove blank option from the country dropdown

1) create di.xml file in app/code/Mymodule/Custom/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection">
            <plugin name="remove-empty-space" 
                type="Mymodule\Custom\Plugin\Country\Collection"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

2 ) create plugin in the app/code/Mymodule/Custom/Custom/Plugin/Country/Collection.php

```
class Collection
{
    /**
     * Arguments processing.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $subject
     * @param $options
     * @return array|bool
     *
     */
    public function afterToOptionArray(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $subject,
        $options
    ) {
        $result = array_filter($options, function ($option) {
            return empty($option['value']) ? false : true;
        });
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mohammed, can you please update the full code with di.xml also?

Comment: @jafarpinjar , i have updated my code, hope it will help you

Comment: Does not recommend, as it breaks functionality in other place. Product edit page stops opening because of attribute country of manufacture.

Answer (score 1):

this issue fixes via little plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\ResourceModel\Country;

/**
 * Plugin for processing incoming arguments of the method that leading to displaying additional empty dropdown.
 */
class Collection
{
    /**
     * Arguments processing.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $subject
     * @param bool $emptyLabel
     *
     * @return bool|array
     */
    public function beforeToOptionArray(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $subject,
        $emptyLabel = null
    ) {
        return is_null($emptyLabel) ? [''] : null;
    }
}
```

enjoy:)

Comment: Where i need to create this file.?  I have created the file in the vendor. But it did not work.

Comment: You should create **before plugin** (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) it should be like new cusom module (app\code\Vendor\Module\Plugin\ResourceModel\Country)

Comment: @Dmitry, can you please update full code with di/xml also?

Comment: @Dmitry, used the plugin, its not working for me

Comment: @Dmitry, used the plugin but it is not working.